# What does "s.t." mean?

Tags: terminology

English is my second language and I have a question. What does "s.t." mean?

$ \text{min} \quad f(x) = (x_1−2)^2+(x_2−1)^2 $ 
$ \text{s.t.}\qquad g_{1}(x) = x_{1} - 2x_{2} + 1 = 0 $ 
$ \qquad\qquad g_{2}(x) = \frac{x_{1}^2}{4} - x_{2}^2 + 1 \ge 0 $

Comment: *so that* (denotes a condition) 'Minimize $f(x)$ so that $g_1(x) = 0$ and $g_2(x) \geq 0$.'

Comment: I knew "subject to" in an optimization problem formulation and usually "such that" in the other cases.

Comment: (sometimes they use it as "sucht that" as in $\{x: {\rm s.t.\;\; blah})$

Comment: Abbreviation of "such that".

Comment: And if you want to be even more cryptic, there's a symbol you can use, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6282/how-do-i-make-the-such-that-symbol-from-set-theory

Comment: Sort of unrelated, but I have also seen "STS" or "s.t.s." used for "suffices to show". I write this here in case people searching for "sts" will come across this thread.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Usually, the acronym $s.t.$ means **such that**. In the context of optimization, it means **subject to**. Also note that **such that** does not have the same meaning as **so that**.

**Such that**, describes how something should be done.

**So that**, describes why something should be done.

For clarity, it's usually best to avoid $s.t.$ and simply write **such that**.

Answer (score 6):

Usually in optimization problems s.t. is written to denote **subject to** because, an optimization problem is usually of the form:
Optimize f(x) **subject to** the constraint g(x)

In general mathematics and logic, **such that** is written as a colon(:), for e.g.
$${x^2: \exists n > x \forall n \in \mathbb{N} }$$